# ChannelHandlerContext.attr is not accessible from inside userEventTriggered

Tags: java, netty, keep-alive

I am using netty for developing my server.
I am also implementing the Idle state handling in netty.
I got it working but an issue I recently found out.
I can't access the channel context attributes inside the userEventTriggered method.
here is my code and can anybody tell me why it is not possible.

I am setting it like

```
public static final AttributeKey<Agent> CLIENT_MAPPING = AttributeKey.valueOf("clientMapping");
...
ctx.attr(CLIENT_MAPPING).set(agent);
```

and inside handler, I am getting the value like (this is working perfectly)

```
Agent agent = ctx.attr(CLIENT_MAPPING).get();
```

But inside userEventTriggered it is returning null. (I am sure that it is set before this function is being called.)

```
public class Server
{
    ...

    public void run() throws Exception
    {
        ...
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).
                    channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).
                    childHandler(new SslServerInitializer());
        ...
    }
}

class SslServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>
{
    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception
    {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        ....
        pipeline.addLast("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(0, 0, Integer.parseInt(Main.configurations.get("netty.idleTimeKeepAlive.ms"))));
        pipeline.addLast("idleTimeHandler", new ShelloidIdleTimeHandler());
    }
}

class ShelloidIdleTimeHandler extends ChannelDuplexHandler
{
    @Override
    public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception
    {
        if (evt instanceof IdleStateEvent)
        {
            try
            {
                // This I am getting null, but I confirmed that I set the attribute from my handler and is accessible inside handler.
                Agent agt = ctx.attr(WebSocketSslServerHandler.CLIENT_MAPPING).get(); 
                ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(new TextWebSocketFrame("{\"type\":\"PING\", \"userId\": \"" + agt.getUserId() + "\"}"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ctx.disconnect();
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you set and get it in the same ChannelHandler? If you want to set and get it in different ChannelHandler you need to use Channel.attr(...)

Comment: Yes. While the client is connected for the first time I am setting the  ChannelHandlerContext attribute. so whenever the channel is idle, it will call the userEventTriggered with that ChannelHandlerContext, is it?

Comment: Still I am not able to get the attributes